# What happens when I'm called from work on my day off?

Tags: time-off

I'm taking a day off. My boss expects me to check email from home. If I answer emails from home or take a call during my day off, do I have to count this as a day off since I've actually worked?

I am salaried exempt.

Comment: I am salary exempt

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does an exempt employee spend time-off if they're called in during?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57972/does-an-exempt-employee-spend-time-off-if-theyre-called-in-during)

Comment: **Voted to reopen**: this is a common question and has a perfectly valid answer given basic knowledge of the US' employment laws (exempt versus non-exempt status). Any manager or HR staffer should be aware of this concept which makes this **on-topic**.

Comment: It may be valid, but it's also a duplicate (although there is a better answer here than any of the ones on the original). I suggest closing this and suggesting that the answer be posted on the original question.

Comment: @DJClayworth a dupe is not necessary restricted for a question older than other. If a question is better, and has higher quality answer, even though it were asked before other, *that* post should be left open, and the lower-quality one made dupe. The answer was made *here* and answered this specific setup (although similar), moving it may not be so easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you're expected to check e-mails, then it's not a day off and you need to be paid.

As [this article from the Law Office of Kristine A. Sova explains](http://sovalaw.com/blog/2013/08/21/yes-you-do-have-to-pay-employees-for-checking-e-mail-outside-of-work/) (emphasis added):

> ...the reality is that
>   technological tools, both company-issued and personal, have increased
>   employee accessibility, especially when off site or after hours.  This
>   increased accessibility in turn increases the possibility that
>   employees are performing off-the-clock work that should be paid.  And,
>   work that arguably should be paid, but isn’t, creates an avenue for
>   employees to assert unpaid wage claims against their employers.
>
> How can this be?  Through five magic words: “suffer or permit to
>   work.”
>
> **“Suffer or permit to work” means that if an employer requires or
>   allows employees to work, the time spent is generally hours worked,
>   and must be paid.**  The result is that time spent doing work not
>   requested by the employer, but still allowed, **is** generally hours
>   worked, if the employer knows or has reason to believe that the
>   employees are continuing to work and the employer is benefiting from
>   the work being done.

Comment: +1. I was going to answer but the question is currently on hold and you've mentioned the basics. Check [my answer here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/52303/25739) for more details on exempt versus non-exempt status. Note that the question of if and how this time worked impacts OP's PTO *is* off-topic.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate question. Can i suggest posting this answer on the original question?